# function -- minimum number of times you have to add two integers in your set, to reach a number n

Tags: number-theory

Suppose you start with the set {1}.  A "step" consists of adding a number in your set to another number in your set (or possibly the same number), and making the new number a part of your set.  So the first step always results in the new set {1,2}.  The next step could be {1,2,3} or {1,2,4}, and the possibilities branch further from there.

Let f(n) be the minimum number of steps required in order to add the number n to your set.  So f(1) = 0, f(2) = 1, f(3) = f(4) = 2, f(5) = f(6) = f(8) = 3, f(7) = 4.  (Note that f can be decreasing, since f(7) = 4 but f(8) = 3.)

Does this function have a name?  Does it have known properties?

Trivially, you can get to n by generating all the powers of 2 up to n, and then adding the elements represented by a 1 in the binary representation of n.  But, sometimes this is not the quickest way.  To reach 15, the powers-of-2 approach would give you {1,2,4,8,12,14,15}.  But you can also do {1,2,3,5,10,15}.  (I believe 15 is the first number where powers-of-2 is not the fastest route.)

I was thinking about this in the context of raising numbers to the power n.  Assuming that multiplication is expensive, then the minimum number of multiplication steps to raise a number to the power n is f(n).  If n rarely changes, it might be worth finding the minimum number of steps.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003313

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Any particular reason that you posted this as a comment rather than an answer? :)

Comment: Too short.$\mathstrut$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called "addition chains".  The function described in the question is usually denoted l(n) and the properties described in the question have been known for a long time.

Among other surprising facts, it is possible that l(2n) < l(n) ; the first integer where this is true is 375494703.

More information:
http://oeis.org/A003313
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain